# Is there an iPhone App for reading PDF files?

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation, pdf

After having used Eucalyptus and Stanza apps on my iPhone, I really can't read printed books while traveling any more.

What similar app can I use to transfer, store and read my own pdf files on my iPhone?

PS: I know that Stanza has a Windows application that converts PDFs for iPhone, but I am not a Windows user.

Answer (score 14):

[GoodReader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html) is very handy.  You can wirelessly transfer files and you can even add any web content to the GoodReader library simply by  placing a "g" in front of the URL in mobile Safari.

Comment: It has a custom PDF displaying engine which lets you zoom in for a 50X magnification!

Answer (score 7):

My wife uses [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) to read her **existing** PDFs of her knitting patterns [on the iPhone](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/iphone/) - plus she has the benefit of them being available [on the web](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/web%5Fclipper.php), and her [laptop](http://www.evernote.com/about/download/windows.php).  It also has a great free version.

Comment: And it's free too!

Answer (score 7):

As of 21st June, the Apple iBooks app can read and bookmark PDFs.

Comment: My wife and I both use iBook to read PDFs. May not be as full-featured as the others mentioned here but it's working well for us.

Comment: I highly recommend this because safari supports downloading of PDFs right into iBooks. Also i find that the rendering is great, and iBooks' built in brightness display is awesome!

Answer (score 4):

I use [Air Sharing](http://avatron.com/apps/air-sharing/) which creates a virtual drive on your wireless network. I can copy files (including MS Office and PDF files) to my iPhone and view them. There are [other file transfer](http://www.pure-mac.com/iphone/filetransfer.html) apps that do similar things.

If you're starting with documents that are not PDFs (e.g. Word files), you might find reading PDFs inconvenient since PDFs are inherently page oriented. Stanza's FAQ page has an answer about [creating ePub content](http://www.lexcycle.com/faq/how_to_create_epub) from other documents.

Answer (score 2):

[Readdle](http://readdle.com) has an iphone app that allows you to download files in many formats from the web to your iphone.  They give you some free storage space at their site, but you can sync the files to your phone for reading on a plane, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Reader](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/adobe-reader/id469337564?mt=8) by Adobe for iOS can view PDFs

Answer (score 0):

I use [PDFViewer](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/17-iphone-applications-you-should-install/):

> Transfer your PDF files to your iPhone and view them with this application.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use [Calibre](http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/), it can convert PDF and other ebooks into epub and it is compatible with Stanza on the iPhone for downloading docs into the phone.  Internface is definitely not up to Mac standards but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I copy the PDFs I want to read while being mobile into a folder in my DropBox. And I just view them using the DropBox app.

So far, it's ok for simple PDFs, although moving from page to page may stutter a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I generally recommend Evernote for reading PDFs. There are other [iphone apps](http://iphone.appspatrol.com/) that can get the job done, but evernote is front of the pack.

Answer (score 0):

I use Stanza.  I've noticed some minor flaws in rendering slides, but it's more than adequate for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

iBooks can read PDFs, although I think evernote is the best.

Comment: Both iBooks and Evernote have already been mentioned in more detail.